# How to give full permissions to a shared volume in kubernetes

Tags: permissions, kubernetes, volumes

I have a container which is using shared volume with host. I want to give it a full permissions. At present, it is:

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 8 user user 4096 Aug  9 04:47 Data
```

But I want it to be:

```
ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 8 user user 4096 Aug  9 04:47 Data
```

I have a below deployment file:

```
----
----
spec:
  containers:
  - name: logger
    image: logger_image
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /Data
      name: Data-files
    securityContext:  
      privileged: true

 volumes:
  - name: Data-files
    hostPath:
      path: /home/user/Documents/Data

----
----
```

I have even set it as `privileged` but still, the volumes do not have full permissions. What should I add in deployment file to make the volume full permissions?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permissions on `/home/user/` or `/home/user/Documents/` folders don't allow the process' owner (of logger_image) to access the folder and write.

Try to create `/Data` (on your root) and set the proper permissions.

Comment: So if I change the permissions on host, it will also be same on the container side

Comment: You change the permissions on the mount point (Data) and allow the user of logger_image to write in it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by mentioning the appropriate commands to give full permissions to that directory in the `Dockerfile` itself.

In the dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /Data
RUN chmod 777 -R Data/
```

and then later used the same kubernetes deployment file and it worked fine with full permissions.

Thanks